# Extracting relevant tags associated with that particular single post only

Tags: posts, loop, tags

```
  $tags = get_tags(array(
    'hide_empty' => false
  ));
  echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
      echo '<li>' . $tag->name . '</li>';
    }
  echo '</ul>';
```

[image]

The above code is an excerpt of code in `content-single.php`
Everything works fine, but

In the single post, the tag is an individual feature. This is generating an entire tag list on all single posts. How can I put a  constraint so that on single posts pages only those tags are fetched, which are relevant and associated with that stand-alone single post?

Comment: PS: Just so you know, you could actually use `get_tags()` to get the tags assigned to specific post(s) only by using the `object_ids` argument, e.g. `get_tags( [ 'object_ids' => get_the_ID() ] )`, but `get_the_tags()` is easier if getting the tags for a single post only. :)

Comment: You have very deep knowledge. You can help people like us by creating a paid video course on udemy.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the tags (taxonomy: `post_tag`) for a specific post only, then you can use [`get_the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/).

Excerpt from the documentation:

> This function returns an array of objects, one object for each tag
> assigned to the post. If this function is used in [The
> Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), then no ID need be
> passed.
>
> This function does not display anything; you should access the objects
> and then echo or otherwise use the desired member variables.

So in your code, you just need to replace this part:

```php
  $tags = get_tags(array(
    'hide_empty' => false
  ));
```

with this:

```php
  $tags = get_the_tags();
```

However, note that `get_the_tags()` may return a `false` or a `WP_Error` instance, so make sure to check if the `$tags` is a valid array. For example,

```php
$tags = get_the_tags();

if ( is_array( $tags ) && ! empty( $tags ) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        echo '<li>' . $tag->name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

And actually, if you just want to display a HTML list (e.g. an `UL`) with tag names and links, then you can simply use [`the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_tags/) like so:

```php
<?php the_tags( '<ul><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>' ); ?>
```

Comment: It perfectly works, and also thank you so much for the extra credit knowledge.